# How to disable right click on desktop?

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, menu

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and I want to disable the menu that appears when you right-click on your desktop. Actually, I know I can run the command line "xmodmap" to "disable" the right click of the mouse, but that's not the solution I'm looking for. I want to be able to right click in other programs. Is it posible?

Thank you!

Comment: Right click menu is property of Nautilus desktop overlay, which also manages the icons and wallpaper. If you're OK with using `feh` app to set wallpaper on bare X desktop and having no icons, then yes, what you want is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy said in his comment but I couldn't managed to work it out with `feh` because I need to have at least one icon on my desktop.

However, I found a workaround with the command `xmodmap`. I thought a lot how to solve that and I finally got an idea. It was enabling right click of the mouse when the user uses a specific program, so I did a bash script which checks if the program is running. If the program is running, right click works, simple. Then I did another script to keep the other one running every 5 seconds (for example) and make it run on startup.